# data-press in view doesn't seems to be working, What am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

In `open ui5` I am using `data-custom-data:target = "screenName"` in a `div` and I have created 2 files screenName.view.html and screenName.controller.js, when I click on the `div`, it does not takes me to the screen which I am expecting i.e nothing happens when I click. What am I missing here? Should I need to map the screens some where else?

I have tried the following code on `data-press="sometTilePress"`

```
sometTilePress : function(evt) {
    var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    bus.publish("nav", "to", {
        id : "someHome"
    });
},
```

but it gives me an error `Sorry, we can't navigate you there. Cannot read property 'app' of undefined`.

what am I missing now ?

I am newbie, so don't down vote!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a mapping in `App.controller.js` helped me to fix the issue. So we need to map it in the said js to make it work.